# Why is Font Awesome only showing a square?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am trying to replicate the [page linked from Start Bootstrap](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-modern-business/).  All goes fine with the exception of the font-awesome.min.css images.

I am using the same version of font-awesome.min.css and the same code.  My code contains the following, which is taken directly from the page's source code:

```
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-gift"></i>
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-compass"></i>
```

These images are supposed to be shown under the "Welcome to Modern Business" as a checkmark, gift, and compass, respectively.  You can see the link above to view it in context, but this image should explain sufficiently:

[image: Correct Images]

However, in my page, all of these images are shown up as boxes:

[image: Wrong Images]

I cannot figure out why the website linked above pulls the correct images from [font-awesome.min.css](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-modern-business/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css), but my page is not.  I have not changed anything from the original source.  I created an identical hierarchy, and copy and pasted the .css and .js files directly from the source as well.  I have stumbled across this issue before, and I ended up deleting the images because I could not find a solution.  I am hoping to have better luck this time around.  Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you downloaded font-awesome to your project?

Comment: @cchacholiades Yes :-) I used the one linked in my final paragraph. (Copy and pasted)

Comment: what does the inspector says, any not downloaded/404 objects?

Comment: @Mark I always forget to check the console!
http://localhost:63343/MyProject/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
There is one for each image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste this link to the `<head>` of the document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Check if it works.

- Go to:
  http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
- Copy all of the code there.
- Create a `fontawesome.min.css` and store it in your css folder.
- Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome.min.css">
```

Comment: What? Huh?  Why does that work!?  I had <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> in my <head>, but it failed.

Comment: Thank god it works! Probably something went horribly wrong! :p