# Why does CDN work, but a relative link does not?

Tags: css, cdn, font-awesome

I just asked this question:  [Why is Font Awesome only showing a square?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29927276/why-is-font-awesome-only-showing-a-square/29927438?noredirect=1#comment47976762_29927438).

The gist of it is that my [font-awesome.min.css](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css) file was not working.  I was getting 404 errors when trying to load icons from it.  Someone gave the ridiculous suggestion of changing:

```
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

I tried their suggestion with confidence that it would not change anything, but it worked!

The code in `MyProject/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css` (the filepath is correct) is identical to the code at `//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css`.

Why is it that the CDN works, but my local copy gives me 404 errors?

Some clarification:

The file is being found when I try to link to the relative file (not using the CDN).  The images within the CSS come up with 404.  But with identical code at the CDN, there is no 404 for the images.  I get the following error for each respective image:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http://localhost:63343/MyProject/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0
```

Comment: Is the page you are viewing at the same level as font-awesome or further down?

Comment: @zimdanen MyProject/index.html is where I am viewing it.  The top-level folder.

Comment: @Barmar that is where it is.

Comment: Can you check the server's access log to see what folder it's looking in when it gets the 404 error?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't copied the image files to your server.

Comment: @Barmar updated question with that info.  And I certainly did *not* copy the image files to my server.  I did not know that was a thing.

Comment: What is your server's static file directory set to?

Comment: @thgaskell Uhhh...I don't know what that means.  I am by no means a web developer.  I have to do a lot more research before I can answer that.

Comment: @Evorlor in the answer below, when you put the `/` in front of the path, what does the _new_ 404 error look like?

Comment: The error isn't for icon images, it's for a font file. You need to copy the `fonts` directory to your server.

Comment: @thgaskell http://localhost:63343/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Barmar Gotcha.  Cuz I am assuming they aren't images at all, but characters in a font, or something along those lines.  Considering I am too green to understand copying directories and servers and whatnot, I am just going to use the CDN for now.  I thank you all for your help!!  If one of you wouldn't mind answering my question for potential future newbies, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS file refers to font files using relative URLs. So when you copy the CSS, you also have to copy the font folder to `MyProject/font-awesome/fonts`.

Basically, when you download the Font Awesome ZIP file, you should extract the entire thing into `MyProject/font-awesome`. This will get you the all the files and they'll be in the proper location.

Answer (score -1):

You are pointing to the absolute url. Try changing it to relative to Home page. Ex: /font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css.

Comment: Adding the `/` in front caused the file to not be found.

Comment: You have _absolute_ and _relative_ backward. Starting with `/` makes it absolute.

Comment: @Evorlor The code without `/` also caused the file to not be found.

Comment: @Barmar No....without the `/`, the file is found.  The *images* get the 404 on this case.